# apt-get update: Unable to find expected entry 'Packages' in Release file

Tags: apt, deployment

We have an automated build and deploy process based on `debootstrap` and `apt` for creating image files for one of our products directly after the build on the build-server.

The `sources.list` is a bit strange, but works as long as the target-host does *not* trust the GPG key for signing the release:

```
root@host:/# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://buildserver.mycompany.com/project/deploy-test ./
```

While the key is not trusted, the call to `apt-get update` works and everything is fine:

```
root@host:/# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://buildserver.mycompany.com/project/deploy-test ./

root@host:/# apt-get update
Hit http://buildserver.mycompany.com ./ Release.gpg
Hit http://buildserver.mycompany.com ./ Release
Ign http://buildserver.mycompany.com ./ Release
Ign http://buildserver.mycompany.com ./ Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://buildserver.mycompany.com ./ Packages
Ign http://buildserver.mycompany.com ./ Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done              
W: GPG error: http://buildserver.mycompany.com ./ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 65F8A65265A41039
root@host:/# echo $?
0
```

If I then add the build server's key, things start to get strange:

```
root@host:/# apt-key add /etc/apt/buildserver.gpg 
OK
root@host:/# apt-get update
Get:1 http://buildserver.mycompany.com ./ Release.gpg [490 B]
Hit http://buildserver.mycompany.com ./ Release
Fetched 490 B in 0s (17.4 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://buildserver.mycompany.com/project/deploy-test/./Release  Unable to find expected entry 'Packages' in Release file     (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@host:/# echo $?
100
```

Research on the internet indicated, that the `Packages` file is either missing on the webserver (it is not, only `200`  status responses for all requests in the server's log) or that the checksum is missing from the `Release` file. But this is not the case:

```
root@host:~$ curl http://buildserver.mycompany.com/project/deploy-test/./Release | grep Packages
 dc7048e30031d700ec50c0ea084f69da   606332  Packages
 6a601e7da66b2a518bdf901ef95b53b5   171774  Packages.gz
```

Any hint what could cause this behaviour is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!